# If I have three checkboxes on my asp.net webform ..if 1 is already checked om pageload then..

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If I have three checkboxes on my asp.net webform.. if 1 is already checked on pageload event then output in textbox would be 2,3 if 2 and three checkbox would be checked... even after.

I want if the checkboxes are already checked on page load event, we have to ignore that checkboxes, and add recently checked checkboxes, checkbox2 and checkbox3, will be entered in textbox 1 as 2,3.

I would like this in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf (cntrl) Is CheckBox Then
                If CType(cntrl, CheckBox).Checked = False Then
                    TextBox1.Text = CType(cntrl, CheckBox).Name
                End If
            End If
Next
```

If this solves your question please do mark it..

Answer (score 0):

take id of the checkbox checked on page load in a variable and write a condition such that
it is a pseudo code and not the code.
It just tell you how the working should occur.

if(chkname != checkbox.checked.name)
txt1.text = checkbox.checked.name;

Comment: deepika..i dont have any idea of this ..can u plz generate the sample code for me ... using three checkboxes because i have to implement it with more than 50 checkboxes